Running excel worksheet in the background
At the moment, I am working with a Productivity Macro worksheet as it helps me work quicker. However, I have adjusted my Advanced Settings in Excel to open this specific Excel workbook "at start-up".
However, I would like to have this worksheet running when using Excel without having it "physically" open. I know this should be possible.
Any tips?
I tried going thtourgh all settings but could not find the solution.
I tried going through all Excel options (mostly advanced) but I did not find any solution.

What about something like a shortcut with properties set to minimised?

Why do you think this should be possible? You're talking about performing calculations in a file which is not even opened, aren't you?

Perhaps either create a PERSONAL.xlsb workbook, or an add-in (.xlam).
